# how to send a Map from child process to parent process

Tags: node.js, process, child-process

I fork a child process with `worker` module. I wanted to return the result of a map from the child process after it's done some work to the parent process but it doesn't work. The size of the map is pretty large and I am not sure if that's the reason. How do I send a map to the parent process from child process?

```
function doWork() {
    var child = cp.fork(__dirname + '/work');
    child.on('message', function(m) {
      console.log('completed: ' + m.results);
    });
    child.send({
      msg: 'do work',
      name: self.myname
    });
}
```

worker.js

```
var results = {};
process.on ("message", function (m){
  // work populates results map
  work(m.name);
  process.send({
    msg : 'DONE',
    // somehow this doesn't work
    results: JSON.stringify(results)
  });
});
```

If I remove `result` then it works. I could get the msg in the parent process.

```
var results = {};
    process.on ("message", function (m){
      // work populates results map
      work(m.name);
      process.send({
        msg : 'DONE',
      });
    });
```

Comment: How big is it? What do you mean it doesn't work? Is there an error being thrown out? Stuck while idle? Or stuck with CPU 100%? Or there's a missing property?

Comment: it's big .. the map has about 1M rows .. ` console.log('completed: ' + m.results);` this never get printed ..